# Redirection in ASP.NET MVC to a controller method after the post AJAX call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Present set up -

```
url: configMap.sitePath + "api/Quiz/" + quizResponse.quizId,
                    data: JSON.stringify(quizResponse),
                    success: function (data) {
                       // Display the data on UI 
                    }
```

the above post is to a .NET api controller which returns `quizResponse`.

```
    [ValidateModelState, HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id, QuizResponse value)
```

Now as per a new requirement , Once the api has the response I should redirect to another page(a MVC controller and then view). How do I achieve this -

```
    public ActionResult ScptResult()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I also thought of redirect after ajax success but not sure if its a correct way.
Also, How do I pass data to the `scptresult` controller method after post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: @lopezbertoni Thanks for looking. but this is diffrent . its MVC.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the success function of your JQuery, redirect the page to your MVC page:

```
window.location = '{controller}/{action}/{quizid}';
```

Assuming you use the standard MVC routing, and assuming you change your ScptResult function to accept a parameter, so you can pass data to it.

```
public ActionResult ScptResult(int quizid)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I should warn, I'm not very familiar with ajax responses but hopefully this gets close.

API

```
[ValidateModelState, HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id, QuizResponse value)
{
    //Other stuff...
    var redirect = string.Format(@"/controller/ScptResult/{0}", id);
    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(redirect)
    };
}
```

Javascript

```
url: configMap.sitePath + "api/Quiz/" + quizResponse.quizId,
                data: JSON.stringify(quizResponse),
                success: function (data) {
                   window.location = data; 
                }
```

Controller

```
// This follows the default route. 
// "/{controller}/{action}/{id}" where id is optional.
// window.location = "/ControllerName/ScptResult/OtherData"
public ActionResult ScptResult(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in java-script after complete your work in success method or anywhere

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("ScptResult", "YourControllerName")';
```